# Help with disappearing bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a strange problem with the bibliography (I use bibtex) for latex (to compile I use TexniCcenter 2.0 beta, but the problem remain even if I compile with Texworks or winedt).

I am writing a thesis, and compiling two or three chapters (via the \input command), the bibliography works well without warnings.

Once I put others chapters (so that the total number of chapter is 4 or 5 with the appendix), it is not able anymore to compile even a single reference and the whole bibliography disappear. (I tried even to change the bibliography limit from 99 to 200 or 300, but it does not work). Here there is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{showkeys}%togliere nella versione definitiva
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{natbib} 
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eucal}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\input{Introduction.tex}
\input{Chap1.tex}
\input{Chap2.tex}

\appendix
\input{Appendix1.tex}
\input{Appendix2.tex}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  you might want to check that none of your chapter or appendix files end with `\end{document}`.  (i've been known to make this bonehead error on more than one occasion, and indeed, it's frustrating when the last part of a job disappears.)

Comment: Can you pinpoint which `\input` (if any) is responsible for the behaviour? It might also be worth a try to examine the `.log` file for statements concerning bibliography and citations and to have a look at the output of a `bibtex` run.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error in an input file